# Bisection by C - a basic beginner's q

Tags: c

I am writing up a code for the **bisection method**.

My code's below, and somehow the loop doesn't seem to start.

There are no special compiling issues.

I don't think there are any problems with the variable declaration / function prototypes.

Can anyone help me find the real issue here?

Comment: _"somehow the loop doesn't seem to start"_ What makes you believe that?

Comment: Please, create a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom thank you for the advice! I'll try referring to it

Comment: @Michael I can compile my programme, but when I key in the inputs ssh returns a blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [binary search algo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) goes like:

```
do {
    m=(a+b)/2; /* Change 1, 4 lines */
    pA=polynomial(a,c3,c2,c1,c0);
    pB=polynomial(b,c3,c2,c1,c0);
    pM=polynomial(m,c3,c2,c1,c0);

    if(pA*pM<0) {
        b=m;
    }
    else {
        a=m; /* Change 2, 1 line */
    }
} while(pM!=0 && fabs(a-b)>0.0001);
```

You need to conditionally change both `a` and `b` to converge (reach closer to exit condition) and recalculate `pA`, `pB` and `pM` in each iteration.

There is some scope of optimization (avoid some recalculation) that I hope you can figure out once you can get the code to work to your expectation.